# The storage account for this workspace has been deleted

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-machine-learning-service

The storage account for this workspace has been deleted. which I have been using for my Machine Learning Studio. What should I do as when I try to save my experiment it shows that no workspace is found.

[See the Image for reference which showing storage account has been deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hsb99.png)

Answer (score 0):

Deepak, this issue maybe related to cache on your browser or a deleted storage account for the workspace.

**For scenario one (which you are getting):**

After the new Machine Learning workspace is created, you can sign in to Machine Learning Studio by using the Microsoft account you used to create the workspace. If you encounter the error message, “Workspace Not Found” (similar to the following screenshot), please use the following steps to delete your browser cookies. More details can be found here: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/troubleshooting-creating-ml-workspace`, you can also use in private/incognito mode to confirm.

**Scenario 2:**

In case if the storage account was deleted, double check in the Storage accounts on the left blade of the azure portal, then select the subscription you created the workspace with, it should list it there, if it is not, then it was indeed deleted. In that case:

"It's not possible to restore a deleted storage account or retrieve any of the content that it contained before deletion. Be sure to back up anything you want to save before you delete the account. This also holds true for any resources in the account—once you delete a blob, table, queue, or file, it is permanently deleted." More details can be found here: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-create-storage-account`